# Neural network to decision tree

Tags: classification, neural-networks

Nn is a powerful tool with good approximation properties.

Decision trees are easy to interpret.

Let's have a perfectly tuned neutral network for some data, all parameters and hyperparameters, regularizations, validations etc.

How to construct a decision tree as good as possible out of that?

My approach: 1. get the distribution of input data, sample from that many samples 2. predict the output for them 3. using this data set, find optimal decision tree e.g. by genetic algorithms.